# Hide/Remove Permission-Policy header warnings in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, header, http-headers, warnings, http-permissions-policy

We have added new permission policies in our application's web.xml file. Since then, we've been watching these warnings in google chrome's (MS Edge as well) console. Also, this is not visible in Firefox.

[image: google chrome console warnings output]

Is there a way we can elegantly hide or remove these warnings? We haven't been able to find anything after our due R&D. We would really not like our clients to see these warnings.

P.S. it's obvious that we cannot remove these permission policies.